# Point > Align Rotation to Vector Node is missing in 3.0 and 3.1

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to follow along this tutorial by [Erindale on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Y_lMMsFeXg)

I am using blender 3.0 as he suggests in the beginning of the video. Same as he is using.

I reach a point in the video (10:04) where he creates a "Align Rotation to Vector" node. This is selected as a sub-menu option in the "Point" Menu. For some reason, this does not exist in the version I am using, but it does in his?

I searched all the options in the top search bar, and the node is gone.

I tried blender 2.97, and boom the Point menu, and sub-menu are there, with the missing node. But other nodes required for the project are missing.

Has this node been removed/renamed since this tutorial was created in June 2021?
Do I need to downgrade to a different (non-beta) version?

[image: tutorial]

[image: Mine]

Comment: I've also tried 3.1 Alpha, still nothing.

Comment: It's called Align Euler to Vector I think now.

Comment: Since they completely overhauled geometry nodes for 3.0, there's so much tutorial content out there (based on 2.9) that doesn't work anymore. You might be able to adapt what you're doing there to something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3mnV.png

Answer (score 1):

To give some context to Ewo's answer:

In the video, Erindale is using an early Version of Blender 3.0 alpha.
This attribute-driven approach of Geometry Nodes has since been overhauled and replaced with what's called 'fields'.

That is why none of the nodes in the release version of 3.0 (or any build of 3.1 for that matter) look like they did in the tutorial. It's a completely different system now.

If you still want to follow the tutorial closely, you can reactivate the old system. (As described in Ewo's answer.) Keep in mind that you'll only see the "Experimental" tab if you have "Developers Extras" enabled under "Interface"

Answer (score 0):

*You have to enable Geometry Nodes Legacy under the settings:*

**Edit > Preferences > Experimental > Geometry Nodes Legacy**

```
(and don't forget to Save Preferences)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Align Euler to Vector** with either **Transform** or **Vector Rotate** + **Set Position** on 3.0+ to perform that operation.

I don't have the time or patience to watch the tutorial to figure out if you're modifying real geometry or instances, but if it's instances you'll also need to **Realize Instances** before altering their rotation.